# Trying to solve an error problem with Matlab v 9.13 when doing matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, matrix, rank, svd

Here is the problem and current code I am using.

Use the `svd()` function in MATLAB to compute , the rank-2 approximation of . Clearly state what  is, rounded to 4 decimal places. Also, compute the root-mean square error (RMSE) between  and . Which approximation is better,  or ? Explain.

Solution:

```matlab
%code
[U , S, V] = svd(A)

k = 2

V = V(:,1:k)

V = transpose(V)

Ak = U(:,1:k) .* S(1:k,1:k) .* V

diffA = A - A2

fro_norm = norm(diffA,'fro')

RMSE2 = (fro_norm)/sqrt(m*n)
```

However, when running, the line `AK = . . .`  keeps giving an error because the matrix sizes are not compatible.  So I understand that the matrix sizes need to match in order to do the multiplication, but I also know that the problem requires the following calculation requirements, that when `k = 2`, `U` has to use the first 2 columns, `S` has to use the first 2 rows and first 2 columns, and `V` has to be the transpose of `V` only using the first two columns.

I must be missing something in my understanding of the calculation, or creation of the sub k matrices.  The matrix I have to use is a 3 x 3.

Comment: Your problem description is missing some equations, I guess. Please [edit] your post to clarify what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: `.*` is element-wise multiplication, `*` is matrix multiplication. You probably want to do `U * S * V'`.